# Workaround non-themeable properties (specifically asp:Button OnClientClick)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, themes, onclientclick

Retrofitting ASP.NET WebForms themes to an old application I have a need to theme an `<input>` tag such that the JavaScript click event is different for each theme. I replaced with tag with an `asp:Button`, only to disciver that the `OnClientClick` property is not themeable.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: How would a themeable OnClientCick work?

Comment: @Chuck: Different JavaScript for each theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ThemeableButton**

You have to create a simple class that derived from `Button`. Then override the `OnClientClick` property and add a `Themeable` attribute to as follows.

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Button runat=\"server\" />")]
public class ThemeableButton : Button
{

    [Themeable(true)]
    public override string OnClientClick
    {
        get { return base.OnClientClick; }
        set { base.OnClientClick = value; }
    }

}
```

**Web.Config**

Now, you have to replace the old button with new one. Change the `pages` section as follows.

```
<pages>
  <tagMapping>
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         mappedTagType="[Namespace].ThemeableButton, [AssemblyName]" />
  </tagMapping>
</pages>
```